# telerik radcombobox "OnClientTextChange" event doesn't fire

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I wrote the following code, based on telerik examples:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPageSize"   
runat="Server"   
skin="Gray"  
AllowCustomText="true"  
Style="float:right; margin-left: 5px;"   
Width="60px" 
OnClientTextChange = "PageSizeChanged"
OnClientSelectedIndexChange =  "PageSizeChanged">

<Items>
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="Server" Text="10" Value="10" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="Server" Text="20" Value="20" Selected="true" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="Server" Text="50" Value="50" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="Server" Text="150" Value="150" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="Server" Text="250" Value="250" />
</Items>

</telerik:RadComboBox>


<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="rcb" runat="server">

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function PageSizeChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

        alert("You typed " + sender.get_text());

    }

</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

When I change the selection, the function "PageSizeChanged" is called, but when I change the text by typing inside the combobox, the function is never called.

Anyone has a suggestion why?
Thanks,
Inbal.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's definitely a 'feature' of this Telerik control.  If you use your code, type something, press enter and then click outside the box the event will fire.

Just pressing enter or just clicking outside don't fire it on their own.

I'm using a slightly newer version of the Telerik controls as the skin Gray has been deprecated but I'm assuming it will be the same in your version.

Answer (score 0):

OnClientTextChange WILL NOT fire until the user hits Enter or clicks outside the RadComboBox. Says so here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-onclienttextchange.html

Comment: Thanks Ann, I knowe that.. but it doesn't work even after I click enter or outside the box.

Comment: This control was definitely rushed out the door.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set AutoPostBack="true", to fire server events.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPageSize"  
AutoPostBack="true" 
runat="Server"   
skin="Gray"  
AllowCustomText="true"  
Style="float:right; margin-left: 5px;"   
Width="60px" 
OnClientTextChange = "PageSizeChanged"
OnClientSelectedIndexChange =  "PageSizeChanged">
```

Comment: this is not a server side event , but client !  "onClientTextChange"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There is a typo in your code. The name of the event is 
OnClientSelectedIndexChanged not OnClientSelectedIndexChange

and yes the OnClientTextChange will be fired after you press enter or click off the combo.

Maybe you can use OnClientKeyPressing event it will be fired every time after you press a key